# The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Mesmo tentando instalar oque falta `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext`, ele diz que já está instalado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu tambem já ativei a extensão `extension=php_mbstring.dll`, oque pode ser meu problema ??

Extensões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tem sentido, seu php.ini esta com as extensões .dll, isso seria no windows, vc deve ter feito algo muito errado. Obs: Ao invés de imagem copie os trechos.

Comment: Tudo bem, amanhã vou reinstalar o phpmyadmin, eu coloco imagem por que eu acho que fica mais fácil a visualização, obrigado pela resposta

Comment: O problema é o conteudo do teu phpmyadmin, esta coisa de .dll é windows, vc pode reinstalar o phpmyadmin o quanto quiser o problema é outro. Recomendo que reinstale o php todo, ou verifique esta esta editando o php.ini correto.

Comment: Se não me engano o PHP.ini está em `/etc/PHP/7.0/php.ini`. estou no celular agora, então não tenho certeza

Comment: Ok, vou aguardar então.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, já coloquei a resposta, obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim

Answer (score 4):

O `extension=php_mbstring.dll` seria windows no Ubuntu o correto seria:

```
extension=mbstring.so
```

Sem o prefixo `php_` e com a extensão `.so`, note que usar `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` só vai funcionar para a versão do PHP que esta usando na linha de comando, se tiver mais de uma versão do PHP, tipo php5 e php7 vai ter que alternar primeiro.

Para instalar para o *PHP 7.0* pode tentar este comando:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

PHP 7.1:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

No Ubuntu mais recente creio que mesmo no PHP5 deve especificar a versão (ou quando usa múltiplas versões):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.3-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php5.4-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php5.5-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

Depois de instalar e editar o php.ini deve-se reiniciar o Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Eu só tenho o php7 instalado, e mesmo mudando para `extension=mbstring.so`, continua retornando o mesmo erro, mas de qualquer forma modifiquei a pergunta para você ver melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema executando o comando `apt-get remove --purge php7.0-*` e depois `apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mbstring`.

Comment: Basicamente removeu tudo e reinstalou tudo novamente :)